# Node.js: Cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, sinon

I'm installing a module from the *NPM* registry with this command:

```
npm install dc
```

All files are installed successfully, but `dc` fails to resolve a dependency.

```
$ node web-test.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sinon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nikunj/nik_verve/source/node-v0.10.20/node_modules/dc/test/env.js:25:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 10):

To require the module sinon, you must `npm install sinon`, not some other module.

**Edit:** Since you changed your question to installing *dependencies*, sinon is a `devDependency` for the package [dc](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js), so in order to install it, you must navigate to the module's folder and run `npm install`. An install off of the global registry will not install developer dependencies for you, but a local run of install will install both normal and development dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

`dc.js` has dependency on

`jsdom`, `sinon`, `jquery`, `vows`.

For that install all those dependency

```
npm install jsdom
npm install sinin
npm install jquery
npm install vows
```